# .Net Core 6.0 , MySql Support LongBlob with Entifity Framwork

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blob

given is following .Net Core 6.0 C#-Program
`

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Common;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Blob
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "LongBlob")]
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    }

    class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blob> Blobs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=testblob;user=xyz;password=xyz");
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            insert();
            read();
        }

        private static void insert()
        {
            using (AppContext ctx = new AppContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();
                int blobsize = 50;
                byte[] bytes = null;
                bytes = new byte[blobsize];
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(i % 256);
                }

                Blob one = new Blob {Data = bytes, Name = "Hello"};
                ctx.Blobs.Add(one);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private static void read()
        {
            using (AppContext ctx = new AppContext())
            {
                foreach (Blob blob in ctx.Blobs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{blob.Id}={blob.Data.Length}");
                }
            }
        }
        }
}
```

`

This Project is using the following packages:

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.10
2. MySql.Data 8.0.31
3. MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.7

This program inserts data to a table "Blobs" with some data inkl. a longblob column and reads in a second step that data and also writes the blob-size to the console

Starting this program is working fine.
But when i set blobsize higher (e.g. 50000) then the blobsize is 0.

can anyone help?

best regards

Volkhard

Comment: Try `Pomelo` provider. Oracle's EF Core official provider is buggy and do not supports asyncs.

Comment: Hello @SvyatoslavDanyliv, thanks for the tip - Pomelo is currently no option.